# Exception Handling in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have written some simple on button click code. When I run my application and click on the button, it gives the following Error:

**Unfortunately, MyApplication has stopped.**

Code under the button is following:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            if (v == mCapture) {

                try {
                    CaptureFingerPrint();
                    RegisterFingerprint();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    mTextViewResult.setText(e.toString());
                }

            }
    }
```

I actually don't want to close my application accidentally and display error in label as i done in exception part of the above code which does not restrict my application to close.

Important to mention that i does not face this error in android studio. I face it when APK installed and run directly on mobile,

Please anyone guide how to restrict my application to close on button click and displaying error in label. The same i done in c# without any issue.

Comment: Show your error logcat. Exception might happen for various reason.

Comment: The error should be visible in your logcat. Run "adb logcat" while the error happens, and voila!  Your question is unclear to me, can you rephrase your question? Do you or don't you want the error to be displayed on screen?

Comment: error should be visible on your log cat. if not   write this code under your  exception handling  & search for the error in log cat Log.e("exception",e.toString())  &  edit your question with error log

Comment: My only concerns is to display error in label which i placed in mTextViewResult under excepton. And i think Log.e   can be usable if  mobile is connected to my development machine. But my mobile is disconnected from my development machine. Just need to display error in label without application crashed or stopped without any reason. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without posting the stacktrace, the only reason I see that can make your app crash is `mTextViewResult` being null or `e.toString()` providing a null response. Was `mTextViewResult` properly identified inside the layout? If yes, try replacing `e.toString()` with `"" + e.getMessage()`.

It would be best, though, if you found and checked the stack trace.

Comment: Yes my TextViewResult getting  its value properly. But some time my application crash and close without any reason which iam trying to figure it out. Can you please tell me that is this a right way to write Try Catch to stop application from being crash?  Or there any other way to achieve  this? Thanks.